# Non existence of one to one function

Tags: functions

Show that there exists no 1-1 function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with the property

\begin{equation*}
\forall x \in \mathbb{R},~f(x^2) -(f(x))^2 \geq 1/4.
\end{equation*}

How do I bring in $f(x^2)$ into the inequality.

Any hints are welcome.

(Some wrong arguments were deleted after  wythagoras' comment)

Comment: If we have $y=x/4$, the inequality is not statistified for $x=0$.

Comment: Maybe you should observe that Every one-to-one function on the real line is strictly monotone.

Comment: @k1.M That was the first thing that came to my mind.  But still cannot figure out to bring in $f(x^2)$.

Comment: I answered the question by using of it...

Comment: @k1.M Thank you. But I do not think I could have come up with this. Learnt a new trick today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every one-to-one function on the real line is strictly monotone. Hence $L=\lim_{x\to0^+} f(x)$ exists, also observe that
$$
\infty=1/4+1/4+1/4+\dotsb\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^n f(\frac1{2^{2^{k+1}}})-f(\frac1{2^{2^{k}}})\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(f(\frac1{2^{2^{n+1}}})-f(1/2)\right)=L-f(1/2)
$$
Which contradicts...

Comment: There was a typo and I fixed it...:))

Comment: Very minor edit. You left out the def'n of $L$. +1.